# Hive Cast the Scientific number to Decimal

Tags: hive

SELECT cast(123452.256 as BIGINT);

123452

The above query gives me the integer value,What if i want the decimal part too.Is there any way to cast that?

Comment: An INT value is always without decimals. Have you tried to cast it to DOUBLE or DECIMAL?

Comment: But for the large number its giving me Scientific notation again for the Double

Comment: And what about DECIMAL?

Comment: Decimal is not working,Its giving me the integer value

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-decimal You need to add your desired precision. Try SELECT cast(xyz as DECIMAL(30,8)

Comment: That worked ,Thank You